# Rsync Exclude Remote

Tags: rsync

I try to synchronize content back to a remote server with the difference that server has a new /home/virtual folder what I don't want to touch:

```
rsync -avz --numeric-ids --fake-super --delete --delete-after --exclude='/home/virtual' --stats -e "/usr/bin/ssh -i backupkey" /backups/machine1/home/ root@10.0.0.5:/home
```

Is there a way to tell rsync to do the synchronization, but don't touch that folder?
If I take out the --delete key then the other stuff which needs to be deleted won't get deleted so it's not an option. The exclude directive only seems to apply for the source.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the problem? rsync won't remove excluded files, and if you're still afraid that it does, use `--no-delete-excluded`. Try with `--dry-run` if you're unsure what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly --exclude applies to the source side, not the destination (as you said).  My best recommendation is to move the data you want to keep outside of the destination area. For example, instead of /home/virtual use /keep/virtual

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I could understand the `--exclude` behavior with this, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83403.
The key detail is that slashes position are important. Quoting from the link:

> If you append a slash to the end of the source directory `rsync -a source/ destination` it will copy the contents of source, otherwise `rsync -a source destination` copies the source directory itself to the destination.